# Does installing Ubuntu on D: keep Windows from putting programs there?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows, hard-drive

I'm here with a simple question. I'm tired of using Linux on virtual machine so I want to install on my HDD disk.

Let's say I've Windows 10 on an SSD disk with 128 GB (C:). And I want to install Ubuntu on my another HDD Disk with 1 TB (D:).

If I install Ubuntu on an HDD disk, can I still have all programs from Windows 10 like games, Photoshop installed on D:? If I'm on W10 can I still install programs on D: even if it has Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how do you install Ubuntu on disk D:

If you use full disk for Ubuntu partitions, it will be unusable by Windows.

If you select a part of disk D: to install Ubuntu, you can use the other part as an NTFS partition.

Answer (score 0):

first of all Ubuntu uses a filesystem called ext4 by default, Windows uses NTFS. You cannot nativly even mount (access) the ubuntu drive from windows without relying on 3rd party, sometimes unstable drivers such as Ext2FSD. However, installing windows programs on a drive with ubuntu wouldn't be reccomended as ubuntu cannot run windows software without tools like wine, which may or may not even work.

It seems like you also might be asking that you would wnat to store windows data on the ubuntu driver, but maybe only for accessing it form windows as its a bigger drive?
I suppose you could, again if you could get the drive mounted with some 3rd party driver but by doing this you take a very high chance of screwing up the ubuntu install if you don't know what your doing, especially linux doesn't go by crappy labels like C: or D: they go by paths themselves we call root, or home folders depending on where at in the file system you are, you would only want to store data in /home/user and no where outside of that as those would be system files and such.

The reccomended approach to dual-booting is using a shared hard drive, say a 2TB HDD and partitioning it up so ubuntu gets half and windows gets half. Booting into each sepearately and not allowing either os in the other partition. You can always use another drive it's self, as you mention (especially since windows is already slower than linux itself an SSD greatly improoves windows speed), you could use ssd for windows system, and anothe drive purely ubuntu. Although SSD's are fairly expensive compared to hdd's, im thinking that may be why your only using a 128GB and not any higher so i understand this fully.

I would never actually install windows software to a ubuntu drive, mainly because of the .exe installers and how it exacts data places files all over the drive and even the system it's self. In terms of games and that such as with steam, I would use a seperate drive all together to do that especially because of the size of games.

If you want to copy data (e.g personal data) between each os, I would just rely on using usb sticks for that and not directly accessing the drive from each other.

Also, This all assumes your not encrypting your ubuntu installation with luks, if so I am unaware of any currently mainted software to decrypt it on Windows.

Answer (score -1):

You must *partition* your HDD (we don't call it 'D', that's a Windows label). The Ubuntu partition will run Ubuntu. The Windows Data (NTFS) partition is where you will continue to install Windows programs. You generally cannot install Ubuntu programs to your Windows Data partition. Ubuntu is not a Windows clone, and cannot run your Windows software installed on your Windows Data partition.

A full explanation of partitioning is beyond the scope of a single answer in AskUbuntu. You have a [great deal of research](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/disk-partitions.html.en)  to do to prepare for a safe installation of Ubuntu.

Pro Tip: Partitioning is *dangerous*. ALWAYS back up your system completely to some other media before attempting to partition a disk. This site is littered with threads of folks who wiped out years of valuable data with a single errant keystroke.

Comment: So there's no problem if I keep installing programs on NTFS partition? Thanks for your fast answer sir :)

Comment: Are both drives MBR(msdos) or both gpt(GUID)? And you then need to install Ubuntu in same boot mode as Windows UEFI/gpt or BIOS/MBR. And only shrink NTFS partition with Windows tools and reboot immediately & run chkdsk on that NTFS partition. Then only use Something Else install option. Other options may erase other partitions.

Comment: @CellScript Uubntu doesn't install on NTFS partitions.